# foreach loop at a specific index in PHP

Tags: php

I am using a foreach loop and I am wondering if there is any way to start a foreach loop from a specific loop. Suppose I want to start from 5, here is code for a foreach loop where I want to start a loop from 5.

PHP

```
foreach($_SESSION['quotesArray']['results']['record']['recordSet'] as $item) 
{
    echo $item['company'];
}
```

Comment: Just use a for loop...

Comment: I know using for but I want it to using foreach

Comment: But we don't even know what data you are trying to extract, it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @JamesCoyle I know using for but I want it to using foreach

Comment: Well, that's not what `foreach` is used for. And as it resets the array pointer before starting, using something else to move the pointer before cannot be used

Comment: Why? What benefit would using `foreach` give that `for` doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`array_slice`](https://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php), you could do:

```
foreach (array_slice($theArray, 5) as $val) {
    // ...
}
```

Though, note that `array_slice` will create a partial copy of the original array, which might be a performance consideration.

Comment: does `array_slice` return the value at index 5?

Comment: @KebabProgrammer From the manual: *"array_slice() returns the sequence of elements from the array array as specified by the offset and length parameters."*

Comment: Thanks for clarifiing!

Comment: @KebabProgrammer `array_slice` returns a partial copy of the original array preserving keys, no matter whether numeric or associative.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused, does it return values from lets say index 5 to the end of the array in the partial copy?

Comment: @KebabProgrammer If you follow the link to the manual, you'll get a lot of examples explaining most use cases.

Comment: @Yoshi you closed loop earlier, you put extra `)` after `5)`

Comment: Okay nice, I went to `php.net` for a manual on it, and it adds up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if foreach loop is there and you don't know index values, you can try this,

```
$j = 1;
foreach($anything as $k => $v){
    if($j < 5){
     $j++;
     continue;
    }else{
      // anything
    }
}
```